# CSS positioning with JavaScript-generated divs not working how I expected

Tags: css, javascript

First off, I must apologize. CSS positioning has always been the bane of my existence and this is likely something simple that I'm just completely missing...

Anyway, I have a JS script that's generating divs. Each div is within the parent #container which is absolute positioned. CSS below:

```
#container{
  position: absolute;
}
#container div{
  position: relative;
}
```

The function creating the divs is:

```
function newLine(){
  var id_num = ++line;
  var _new;
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < width; i++){
    _new = document.createElement('div');
    _new.innerHTML = randomChar();
    _new.id = id_num;
    _new.style.left = i*10+'px';
    _new.style.top = 0;
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(_new);
  }
}
```

Everything above is properly initialized. The left positioning works perfectly. The only issue is the vertical positioning. Instead of all the row displaying next to each other, they're progressively increasing away from the top of the div. I'm sure this is something trivial that I'm completely looking over, but I'm stumped... Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Relatively-positioned `<div>`'s act as [block-level](http://www.css-101.org/block-level-elements/index.php) elements and will *effectively* consume `width:100%` unless you `display:inline-block` or `float` them (though, depending upon what you know about their contents, you may be better off making them absolutely-positioned).

Comment: @danlefree I flagged this to reopen and migrate this to stackoverflow it shouldn't be closed but migrated

Comment: @Anagio I believe the underlying question - "How do `div`'s and `position` style declarations work?" - is too general for StackOverflow (though I've made an attempt to answer it in the close comment).

Comment: @danlefree there are plenty of personal questions like this on stack where someone has trouble with their own code. I think it should be migrated and you should let the moderators on stack decide if they should close it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rows as `position: relative` - this lays them out statically and then moves them the specified number of pixels. You want to use `absolute` positioning.